# note: previous implicit declaration of ‘point_forward’ was here

Tags: c

I can't seem to get this recursive function to compile properly, and I'm not sure why.
The code is as follows:

```
void point_forward (mem_ptr m) {
  mem_ptr temp;
  temp = m->next;
  if (temp->next != NULL) point_forward(temp);
  m->next = temp->next;
}
```

My compiler returns this:

> mm.c:134:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘point_forward’ [enabled by default]
>   mm.c:96:2: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘point_forward’ was here

Comment: please paste what you have in line 96

Comment: That is the only other instance of this function in my code.

Comment: please move point_forward above line 96. by moving I mean cut and paste

Comment: you have changed your comment. what's really at the line 96?

Comment: I don't believe that is necessary, as this project is compiled using a makefile. I have defined other functions at the end of the page and they have worked fine in lines prior.

Comment: My original comment was going to include the function that called point_forward. It is simply another function that passes in a struct "mem_ptr m" and I simply pass that to point_forward.

Comment: please try deleting that function on line 96 and try to compile, just to confirm you don't have this error because of "before declaration"

Comment: and answerer guys, please don't HUNT for points and let's be trying to help for real.

Comment: turns out moving the functions around moved. My mistake for assuming otherwise. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: by "moved" you mean worked? glad to hear the problem's solved.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation of why.

Answer (score 19):

The key is in this:

> previous **implicit declaration** of ‘point_forward’ was here

On line 96 you have:

```
point_forward(m); // where m is a mem_ptr;
```

Since the compiler hasn't yet seen a function declaration for `point_forward(m)`, it "implicitly defines" (ie, assumes) a function that returns an int:

```
int point_forward(mem_ptr m);
```

This conflicts with the definition later:

```
void point_forward (mem_ptr m) {
```

---

To fix this, you can either:

1. Put an explicit declaration somewhere before line 96: `void point_forward(mem_ptr m);` This will tell the compiler how to treat `point_forward()` when it sees it on line 96, even though it hasn't yet seen the function implementation.
2. Or, define the whole function above line 96 (move the function definition from line 134 onwards to above line 96).

Here is a little bit [more about declaring functions](http://opencbp.sourceforge.net/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/opencbook/func.prototypes.html).

Generally, for style, I would either:

- If you don't want to use `point_forward()` in any other C files, define it in full:

  `static void point_forward(mem_ptr m) { ..function body goes here.. }`

  at the top of the source file.
- If you want to use `point_forward()` in other C files, put a forward declaration:

  ```
  void point_forward(mem_ptr m);
  ```

  in a header file for other files to include.