# Why can't a char return in the function?

Tags: c

I have this program and it gives me this error, can you explain why? I am new to the c language and want to understand how it works.

### The Code

```
#include "stdio.h"

main()
{
    int calification;
    printf("write a number: ");
    scanf("%c", &calification);
    printf("the calification is %c", search(calification));
}

char search(int number)
{
    if (number == 1)
        return ('a');
    else if (number == 2)
        return ('b');
    else if (number == 3)
        return ('c');
    else if (number == 4)
        return ('d');
    else
        return 'n';
}
```

### the error

```
exercise3.c:11:6: error: conflicting types for 'search'
char search(int number)
     ^
exercise3.c:8:38: note: previous implicit declaration is here
    printf("the calification is %c", search(calification));
```

Comment: Add a function prototype declaration before `main()` so that the call in `main` is done correctly: `char search(int number);`

Comment: Read the documentation for `scanf` again, and turn on compiler warnings so the compiler can help find your bugs.

Comment: You need to tell the compiler what your `search` function looks like **before** you use it, otherwise the compiler assume it returns an `int`. You can *either* put the definition before `main` *or* (probably better) put a **forward declaration** of it (before `main`), like this: `char search(int number);` (on a line on its own).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [note: previous implicit declaration of ‘point\_forward’ was here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182115/note-previous-implicit-declaration-of-point-forward-was-here)

Comment: regarding: `#include "stdio.h"`   The header file: `stdio.h` is a system header, so should be enclosed by: `<stdio.h>`.   Header files that you created (I.E. not system header files) should be enclosed by: `"myheader.h"

Comment: regarding: `main()`  There are two valid signatures for the function: `main()` they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Notice they both have a return type of `int`

Comment: regarding: `int calification;` and `scanf("%c", &calification);`  The input format conversion specifier `%c` is for a `char`, not a `int`.  And the `search()` function is expecting a `int` parameter.  Also, when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  Therefore, Suggest:  `if( scanf("%d", &calification) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for the calcification value failed\n" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }` (cont)

Comment: (cont) Note: error messages are output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Note: the `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via the header file: `stdlib.h`

Comment: thanks!
why does this happen? Why do I have to type search before main? I ask why I would like to understand how c works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare functions below `main()` and you want to use them there, you should tell the compiler that such function exists, which means your code be:

```
#include "stdio.h"

char search(int number); // that is the line your code was missing before

int main(void)
{
    int calification;
    printf("write a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &calification);
    printf("the calification is %c", search(calification));
}

char search(int number) { ... }
```

There is also a small problem in `scanf`, which I have fixed. If your input's type is `int`, you need to read the value using `%d` instead of `%c`, which is meant to be used for `char`. Without it `search(number)` would compare `number` with the ASCII value - that means for input 1, 2, 3, 4, the returned value would be `'n'` instead of `'a'`, ..., `'d'`.

Comment: regarding: `void main()`  Per the C standard, that is not a valid signature for `main()`

Comment: many thanks!
why does this happen? Why do I have to type search before main? I ask why I would like to understand how c works

Comment: The simplest answer is that compiler does not know that such `search(int)` function exists. If you mention it over the body of `main`, then it looks for that pattern when you try to call the function somewhere in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `search` **before** you declare `main`.

Comment: many thanks!
why does this happen? Why do I have to type search before main? I ask why I would like to understand how c works

Comment: @JoséJavierPáez The compiler is evaluating this document from top to bottom. `main` has to at least be aware of `search`'s signature to be able to use `search`. That's why @Eric corrected me. You can layout all the details for `search` later on in your code, but you at least have to declare the signature ahead of time if you intend on using it.

Comment: So, you can either move the entire definition of `search` above `main`, or simply place `char search(int number);` above the `main`, leaving the meat and potatoes of `search` down below, where they currently are.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define the function, then you can call the function. For that you have to put the function above the main():

```
#include "stdio.h"

char search(int number)
{
    if (number == 1)
        return ('a');
    else if (number == 2)
        return ('b');
    else if (number == 3)
        return ('c');
    else if (number == 4)
        return ('d');
    else
        return 'n';
}

main()
{
    int calification;
    printf("write a number: ");
    scanf("%c", &calification);
    printf("the calification is %c", search(calification));
}
```

Comment: many thanks!
why does this happen? Why do I have to type search before main? I ask why I would like to understand how c works